# What is currently most widely used set collection in C++

Tags: c++, containers

I'm searching for a set container in C++. I want something where I could add elements but they would not repeat more than once and search in that collection would be O(1). What is current defacto cross-compiler container for this now. 
I seen some in boost (like mpl) and there is one in future c++ standards, but what is best to use now and here?

**EDIT**

Example of storing vector in boost::unordered_set container. So for me it seems to fit my need pretty well but I will have a lot of data in it so if somebody sees some potential bug right away can you comment on what can go wrong. Again, all elements will be of sorted vector with no pointers.

```
vector<string> values1;
values1.push_back("aaa");
values1.push_back("bbb");
values1.push_back("ccc");

vector<string> values2;
values2.push_back("aa");
values2.push_back("bbb");
values2.push_back("ccc");

vector<string> values3;
values3.push_back("aaa");
values3.push_back("bbb");

vector<string> values4;
values4.push_back("aaa");
values4.push_back("bbb");
values4.push_back("ccc");
values4.push_back("ddd");

vector<string> values5;
values5.push_back("aaa");
values5.push_back("bbb");
values5.push_back("ccc");


vector<string> values6;
values6.push_back("aaa");
values6.push_back("bbb");
values6.push_back("ccc");
values6.push_back("ddd");

boost::unordered_set<vector<string> > collection;
collection.insert(values1); // 1
cout << collection.size() << endl;
collection.insert(values2); // 2
cout << collection.size() << endl;
collection.insert(values3); // 3
cout << collection.size() << endl;
collection.insert(values4); // 4
cout << collection.size() << endl;
collection.insert(values5); // 4
cout << collection.size() << endl;
collection.insert(values6); // 4
cout << collection.size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [std::unordered_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982739.aspx) if you have a C++0x compliant compiler that supports it.

If you are not in that situation, intercepts are available in Microsoft VC++ as [stdext::hash_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982739.aspx), or in general using [boost::unordered_set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/unordered.html).  The latter is your best bet for portability at present, pending wider C++0x availability.  As noted in the comments by @Nemo, there is widespread support for `std::tr1::unordered_set` as well, as an alternative to Boost usage.

[`std::set` will be O(log n), as it's based on a search tree. To get O(1), you need to use a hashtable-based container, with due regard to efficient implementation of the hash function for your member objects.]

Comment: By the way. Can you also comment on how boost::unsorted_set would manage more complicated objects. Say a std:vector.

Comment: From a mechanical point of view, it will work the same as with any other object - the key is always coming up with a good hashing function to minimize collisions and yet not kill performance. That's going to be harder for complex objects than it is for say `std::string`, which in itself is hard enough.

Comment: It all depends on how you create your hash-function for that vector object.  For instance, would you search element-by-element, sort of like `memcmp` does for a data array, checking whether each element is the same, greater than, or less than each other, and then determining if the vector is equal, greater, or less than the other vector when the first mis-match occurs?  If you did that, you could see how the hash-function could be pretty slow compared to the actual hash-table insertion time (i.e., linear compared to constant time).

Comment: BTW, will the default boost hash function work in case of vector<string>. No pointers here. And as far as I know vector stores values of string and not pointers. So will two vectors with same elements will have same hash?

Comment: From my small test it seems to be. Can somebody confirm it?

Comment: There is background on hash function usage here - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html.  I'd be surprised if it just works for element type `std::vector<std::string>>` but cannot find anything definitive to say it won't.

Comment: Do not forget `std::tr1::unordered_set`.  Supported with the same interface on every C++ compiler post-2004 or so.

Comment: Can you comment on some additional information I added in the question itself?

Comment: @Sergej - not really, beyond what I already noted.  If it's working for you then great, but that small test likely does not properly mirror your live usage.  I would step through the hash function to see if it's really going to distinguish between dfferent vectors as well as you need.

Answer (score 4):

C++03: `boost::unordered_set`

C++0x: `std::unordered_set`

Older implementations (`stdext::hash_set` in VC++) are not cross-compilers.

*Note: `boost::unordered_set` interface has been reused for `std::unordered_set`, so the migration is easy too*

**edit:** interesting addition ==> if performance is a worry and you want a quick test for the absence, you might be interested in looking up Bloom Filters.

Comment: `std::tr1::unordered_set` is supported by Microsoft, Apple, and GCC for the past six years at least.  In what sense is it not "cross-compilers"?

Comment: @Nemo: I am not talking about `std::tr1::unordered_set` but about the `std::tr1::hash_set` (name varying from compiler to compiler) which the compilers provided before `unordered_set` came to being, and which are actually the reason why we call the new one `unordered_set` and not `hash_set`: to avoid collision and confusion.

Comment: @Matthieu:  I thought TR1 was [Technical Report 1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf), a document released by the C++ working group.  It defines the `std::tr1` namespace and definitely does not include any `hash_set`.  Are you saying some compilers put their own symbols into the `std::tr1` namespace?

Comment: @Nemo: I thought so, I may be mistaken though, I know VC++ used `stdext::hash_set`, I thought gcc had put `hash_set` in `std::tr1` but perhaps did they simply put it in `std`.

Comment: @Matthieu:  gcc had it as `__gnu_cxx::hash_set`.  I do not think even they would pollute a standard namespace :-).

Comment: @Nemo: given both gcc and Microsoft willingness to activate "extensions" by default (VLA for gcc and binding to non-const ref for VC++), I would not put it past them :p I corrected the answer anyway, thanks for noting :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a set that is based on a hash-table in order to get O(1) search time (i.e., constant search time), so that would be `std::unordered_set` and/or `boost::unordered_set`.  The current C++03 `std::set` and `std::multiset` are based on a RB-tree, and therefore have O(log n) search time.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to have a look at the [HashSet](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.HashSet.html) class from the [Poco C++ libraries](http://pocoproject.org/).

Comment: Never heard about Poco. Is it cross platform? Will I be able to easily port it?

Comment: @Sergej Yes it's cross-platform.